# How to handle error of no records in Yii2 find method?

Tags: activerecord, datatables, yii2, find

I show some fields of users info in a grid using DataTables plugin in a project is developed with Yii2.

I have this code to get last visit of each user:

```
$lastDate = SeenLog::find()->where(['user_id' => $this->id])
        ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
        ->one()->visit_date;
```

but I am given this error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=w0 - Trying to get property of non-object and nothing shows in grid.
```

It seems it is because there is no record for some users in table.

How can I handle this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check first if log has been fetched from DB.

```
$log = SeenLog::find()->where(['user_id' => $this->id])
        ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
        ->one();
$lastDate = $log ? $log->visit_date : null;
```